# Почему не срабатывает nth-child(n+3)?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Должно убраться закругление в левой части у  history, кнопок может быть несколько.

И можно еще как то сократить код, возможно убрать что то лишнее или оптимизировать?

```css
.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #55565a;
  padding: 0.15rem 0.425rem;
  border-radius: 0.55rem;
  min-height: 22px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn-radio {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-check {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
}
.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-group > .btn:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.btn-group > .btn:not(:last-child) {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.btn-group > .btn:nth-child(n+3) {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.btn-check + span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.15rem 0.425rem;
  border: 1px solid #46464a;
}
.btn-check:checked + span {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e99a1d;
  border-color: #e99a1d;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check" checked>
    <span>Active</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check">
    <span>History</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что `n+3` обозначает все кнопки начиная с третьей, а у вас кнопок всего две. Возможно, вы хотели `n+2`?

Comment: Ну и непонятно чем вам `.btn:not(:first-child)` для этой цели не угодил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #55565a;
  padding: 0.15rem 0.425rem;
  min-height: 22px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn-radio {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-check {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
}
.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-group > .btn:first-child {
  border-radius: 0.55rem 0 0 0.55rem;
}
.btn-group > .btn:last-child {
   border-radius: 0 0.55rem 0.55rem 0;
}
.btn-check + span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.15rem 0.425rem;
  border: 1px solid #46464a;
}
.btn-check:checked + span {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e99a1d;
  border-color: #e99a1d;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check" checked>
    <span>Active</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check">
    <span>History</span>
  </label>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check" checked>
    <span>Active</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check">
    <span>History</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check">
    <span>Tralala</span>
  </label>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check" checked>
    <span>Active</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check">
    <span>History</span>
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check">
    <span>Tralala</span>
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type[]" class="btn-check">
    <span>И еще раз</span>
  </label>
</div>
```